Django ORM model 'save' method and race condition / ACID Isolation
if we examine the following code:
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.validate_unique()
        super().save()

    def validate_unique(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().validate_unique(*args, **kwargs)
        
        # Doing an ORM query on the model with *filter* on the model attributes & an associated model, 
        # and if exist - dont create a new instance, if not - create a new instance.
        is_duplicated = SomeModel.objects.filter(name=given_name_from_user, attribute_from_associated_model=some_attr)
        if is_duplicated:
             raise Exception("go wrong")
        # Else - continue to save

Now, it will work with the development server, but not with a production one like gunicorn or uvicorn, because the save method gurantee us atomicity, but not isolation, right?
for us to gurantee isolation, we should use ‘get_or_create’ on the view level?
I’m mistake somewhere?
Any comment will help, Thanks!

get_or_create(..) itself also works with two queries, you can work with a combination of get_or_create(..) and a UniqueConstraint.

Not familiar yet with UniqueConstraint, will take a look (because of the associated model attribute).
Do you want to answer the question, that Ill accept it?

You should use UniqueConstraint. It will be prevented from creating an instance with specific fields with the same value.
Also get_or_create won't create an instance with the same values that provided.
But there is a difference between these two strategies. If you use UniqureConstraint, it will prevent duplicate records from any way you create an instance. But in the get_or_create strategy, it will prevent duplicate instances only when it's called.
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=["name", "attribute_from_associated_model"], name="unique_constraint_name"
        )
    ]


If I understand correctly, you should use Django's unique_together shortcut:
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    foo = models.IntegerField()
    bar = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [('name', 'foo')]

Now when you try to create a duplicate entry, an IntregityError will be thrown:
SomeModel.objects.create(name='t1', foo=1, bar=2)
SomeModel.objects.create(name='t1', foo=1, bar=3)
# django.db.utils.IntregityError

